# Why does comparing created_at to the current Date cause an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use "if statement" that's comparing `created_at` of last posted comment's with today.

However this returns error:

**Application helper**

```
def chat_button(community)
  if community.comments.last.created_at == Date.current.to_date
    'Posted today'
  else
    'No post today'
  end
end
```

Comment: What error does it return?

Comment: @sosborn undefined method `created_at'

Comment: Either community.comments.last is returning a nil object (possible if you don't have any comments saved yet) or you haven't declared all of your associations correctly (community has_many comments)

Comment: @sosborn so you mean, there's no problem with my if statement??

Comment: Whichever way, you need to guard against last being nil, just in case there are no comments, as sosborn says.

Comment: Your if statement is fine. In these situations you need to really pay attention to the error messages, Rails is really good about giving an idea of what is happening.

Comment: @cat if your message is `undefined method 'created_at' for nil:NilClass`, most likely `community.comments.last` is returning nil. I'd suggest loading up rails console and testing this in there

Comment: I changed it to this  `if !community.comments.nil? && community.comments.last.created_at == Date.current.to_date` however I get nil class error:(

Comment: Try `if !community.comments.last.nil? && community.comments.last.created_at == Date.current.to_date`

Comment: @hygyn Thanks:) But now it's showing `No post today`:( I'm sure there is record created today.  Do I need to add `order`?????

Comment: Once you get past the error (and it's probably a `nil`-related issue as others have pointed out), this is still going to fail to do what you want in a subtle way, because you're comparing a `DateTime` (including hours/minutes/seconds) to a `Date`.  Once you get past the `nil` issue, add a `.to_date` after `created_at`.  You can also ditch the `.to_date` on `Date.current`; it's already a `Date`.

Comment: @JimStewart You are right!!! I had to add `.to_date` Thanks

Comment: @JimStewart Can you please post as an answer so that I can vote??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing a `DateTime` (`created_at`) to a `Date`.  The hours/minutes/seconds are going to cause the comparison to fail.  Try this:

```
if community.comments.last.created_at.to_date == Date.current
```

Comment: And thanks to the others who commented for resolving the `nil` issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a shorter way to see if a given date time is today.

```
1.minute.ago.today? #=> true
1.day.ago.today? #=> false
```

In your case this would be:

```
comment = community.comments.last
if comment && comment.created_at.today?
```

Note that this method is provided by Active Support from Rails, it doesn't exist in Ruby standard library.